# Why is my react page re-rendering when using react-auth-kit createRefresh hook

Tags: reactjs

Good day all,

Im using the library react-auth-kit (https://authkit.arkadip.dev/integration/) and everything works fine including refreshing the access_token by using the createRefresh hook that is provided out of the box by the react-auth-kit library.

Im also using useContext for state management. The problem is that when the refresh action (which the user of the application should not notice at all) happens every interval, whatever page i'm on the whole application is re-rendered.

Is there a way I can avoid re-rendering the application, when react-auth-kit calls createRefresh method.
Here is main.jsx

```
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <StrictMode>
    <ContextProvider>      
      <App />   
    </ContextProvider>
  </StrictMode>
)
```

Here is App component.

```
function App() {

  const { refreshApi } = useRefreshApi()
  const { note, loaded  } = useAppContext()

  return (    
  <AuthProvider authType = {'cookie'}
              authName={'_auth'}
              refresh={refreshApi}
              cookieDomain={window.location.hostname}
              cookieSecure={window.location.protocol === "https:"}>
     <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>                     
       <AppBar position="absolute" color="secondary" elevation={10}> 
            <Toolbar>
              <Link href="/" sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
                <Box
                  component="img"
                  sx={{ height: 54}}
                  alt="Logo"
                  src={logo}
                />
              </Link>   
              <Header />
            </Toolbar>             
          </AppBar>                  
          <Navigation />          
          <Container >                     
            {note && <NotificationContainer />}
           <Router/>                       
           </Container>
          <AppBar color='primary' />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </AuthProvider>
  )
}
```

Below is my implementation of createRefresh.

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { createRefresh } from 'react-auth-kit'
import { tokenClientId, tokenSecret } from '../config'
import { GetCookie } from '../util/cookieManager'
import { SSO_USER_DETAILS, REFRESH_SSO_TOKEN } from '../util/constants'
import Cookies from 'js-cookie'

const useRefreshApi = () => {
  const refreshApi = createRefresh({
    interval: 4.5,   // Refresh the token in every 4 minutes
    refreshApiCallback: async (
      {   
        authToken,
        authTokenExpireAt, 
        refreshToken,
        refreshTokenExpiresAt,
        authUserState
      }) => {
      try {      
        const headers = {
          'Authorization': 'Basic Auth',
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        }
        const authAction =  axios.create({      
          headers: headers,
          auth: {
            username: tokenClientId,
            password: tokenSecret
          }
        });   
        const grant =  GetCookie('grant');

        if(grant === 'password'){
          let bodyFormData = new FormData();
          bodyFormData.append('grant_type', 'refresh_token');
          bodyFormData.append('refresh_token', refreshToken.toString());      
          const response = await authAction.post('/oauth/token', bodyFormData);                  
          return {
            isSuccess: true,
            newAuthToken: response.data.access_token,
            newAuthTokenExpireIn: 5,            
          }
        }
    
        if(grant === 'authorization'){
          const headers = {
            "RefreshToken": refreshToken
          }          
          const configs = {
            headers: headers,           
          }

          const response = await axios.get(REFRESH_SSO_TOKEN, configs)
          const headers2 = {                
            'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${response.data.access_token}`
          }
          const config = {
            headers: headers2
          }      
          const res = await axios.get(SSO_USER_DETAILS, config)  
          return {
            isSuccess: true,
            newAuthToken: res.data.access_token,
            newAuthTokenExpireIn: 5,                         
          }     
        }

      }
      catch(error){   
        Cookies.remove('grant')                   
        Cookies.remove('_auth_refresh_time')
        Cookies.remove('_auth_storage')
        Cookies.remove('_auth_refresh')
        Cookies.remove('_auth_state')
        Cookies.remove('_auth_type')
        Cookies.remove('_auth')
        Cookies.set('session_expired', true)
      }    
    }
  })

  return { refreshApi }
}

export default useRefreshApi
```

Comment: You are missing a key thing in your post, the code that's using your hook. Nevertheless have you looked into React.memo() ?

Comment: I updated to include App and main files. Maybe my use of useContext is interfering with the library because as per the docs. React-auth-kit also uses React's Context Provider to maintain its state, as per the docs.